# How do I import/handle large text files for MS SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a 1.7GB txt file (about 1.5million rows) that is apparently formatted in some way for columns and rows, though I don't know the delimiter. I will need to be able to import this data into MySQL and MS SQL databases to run queries on.

I can't even open it in notepad to see a sample of the data.

For future reference, how does one handle and manipulate very large data files? What file format is best? To my knowledge Excel and CSV do not support unlimited numbers of rows.

Comment: "ormatted in some way for columns and rows, though I don't know the delimiter" just look in the file

Comment: I don't know how to open the file

Comment: I would also suggest using an Integration Services package. You can split the spindles a bit easier...there are a few methods. Heck, even Bulk Insert might be feasible. P.s SSIS lets you sneakpeak at the csv file.

Comment: Search for "large text file viewer" on google and use that to take a look at your file. Csv files are simple text files, their size is only limited by the operating and file system.

Comment: CSV has no intrinsic limit on the number of rows even if Excel might. Likewise, MySQL doesn't care and you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bcp in as below

```
bcp yourtable in C:\Data\yourfile.txt -c -t, -S localhost -T
```

Hence you know the column name from mysql, you can create table with that structure before hand in sql server